# Zend Framework 2 controller action returning javascript file: error 500

Tags: javascript, http, zend-framework2

I'm trying to do in ZF2 a simple controller action that returns a javascript file.
Simply, what I want to do is something that with PHP you can do in the following way:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/javascript'); ?>
var foo = '<?php echo $bar; ?>';
```

Now, in ZF2 I've an action function of an ActionController like that:

```
public function environmentAction()
{
    $headers = new Headers();
    $headers->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');

    $this->getResponse()->setHeaders($headers);

    $this->layout()->setTemplate('js/environment');

    $view = new ViewModel();
    return $view;
}
```

Then, the route is configured in the following way:

```
'environment' => array(
    'type' => 'Literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/js/environment.js',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
            'action'     => 'environment',
        ),
    ),
)
```

In the end, the view is a .phtml file (the one that is defined in the `template_map` section under the `js/environment` key) like in the simple PHP case:

```
var foo = '<?php echo $bar; ?>'
```

So, all should be done. I simply add a `<script>` element in the head section of my layout.phtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/environment.js"></script>
```

The problem is that in my browser console I get the following error when loading the page:

```
GET ***/js/environment.js 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

but if I try to open the same link in a new page, I success to get the script.

**What's the difference?** In the network section of the developer tools of my browser I see that the http get request for this script and its headers are the same of all the other requests, so why is it acting differently? Why am I getting this error? And in my php log there is nothing about this event. Any idea?

---

**Solved** modifying the action function like that:

```
public function environmentAction()
{
    $headers = new Headers();
    $headers->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');

    $this->getResponse()->setHeaders($headers);

    $view = new ViewModel();
    $view->setTemplate('js/environment');
    $view->setTerminal(true);
    return $view;
}
```

Comment: You should not set a different layout, but instead call `$viewModel->setTerminal(true);` on the view model you are producing.

That _disables_ the layout entirely (which is what you probably need in this case.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you can give an example of what you need to do maybe we can offer better advice for you..

Comment: SOLVED! @Ocramius, I had to set the  template only 'cause the view file is not in the default path `application/index/environment.phtml` but in a different one.

Anyway I deleted the line `$this->layout()->setTemplate('js/environment');` and added `$view->setTemplate('js/environment'); $view->setTerminal(true);` before returning the view and it works! It's anyway strange imho 'cause I think it should work also with the layout controller plugin that should set the root template (if I'm not wrong).

Comment: The `layout` controller plugin changes the layout view model, not the one you are returning.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really bad way of doing things.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/environment.js"></script>
```

This will make the browser make a new request for the file '/js/environment.js' which will again match the route:

```
'route'    => '/js/environment.js'
```

You will get a race condition / endless loop.

Depending on your web server setup, if you request '/js/environment.js' and the file really exists (that is a phyical directory alled js containing environment.js) , then the file will be passed back rather than going to your route anyway which is another undesired effect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrew! Maybe I didn't explain it well. In the general layout I added the `<script>` element with the `src` attribute setted to the environment action, which has not that layout but a terminal view model. So, the race condition should not subsist. :)